# Coin Probability question regarding binomial

Tags: probability

Question: A biased coin is flipped and the odds of getting tails is 2 to 1. If the coin is flipped 60
times; what is the variance of this experiment?

Solution:

Since odds of tails is 2 to 1 odds:

P(Tails)= $ \frac{2}{2+1} $

By complement rule:

P(Heads) = 1-P(Tails) = 1-$ \frac{2}{3} $ = $ \frac{1}{3} $

Binomial where n = 60, p=$ \frac{2}{3} $ and q=$ \frac{1}{3} $

Therefore, variance is (60)$ \frac{2}{3} $$ \frac{1}{3} $= $ \frac{40}{3} $

I am confused as to why the probability of tails is $ \frac{2}{2+1} $ , can someone explain this to me?

Also, why is this considered a binomial distribution?

Answer (score 3):

We know that $\underbrace{P(\texttt{tail})}_{x}+\underbrace{P(\texttt{head})}_{y}=1$

And you have given the ratio of the probabilities: $\frac{P(\texttt{tail})}{P(\texttt{head})}=\frac21=2$

Solving the first equation for x: $x=1-y$

Inserting the expression for $x$ into the second equation.

$\frac{1-y}{y}=2$

$1-y=2y$

$1=3y$

$y=\frac13$

Thus the probability for tail is $1-\frac13=\frac23$

---

$\underline{\text{Another Approach}}$:

We have in total $2+1=3$ parts. $2$ parts belong to the probability of getting head.

Now you take the ratio of $2$ parts (head) and $3$ parts (total): $P(\text{head})=\frac23$.

Similar can be made for $P(\text{tail})$. Or you use $P(\texttt{tail})+P(\texttt{head})=1$

Answer (score 1):

A probability is the ratio between success and all possible outcomes. Odds are the ratio between success and failure. So odds of 2 to 1 means that tails:heads = 2:1. To convert this to probability, we have to take success divided by total. Success is 2, total is 2+1=3, giving the probability as being 2/3.

A Bernoulli trial is when something can have one of two results, with a fixed probability. When several independent Bernoulli trials are performed, the distribution of results is known as a binomial distribution. Since the coin is flipped 60 times, each flip is a Bernoulli trial, and all 60 flips together give a binomial distribution.

Note that if you take the binomial H+T and raise it to the number of trials, you get (H+T)$^{60}$. Expanding that out gives you a sum of terms in which the value of each term is equal to the probability of getting that number of heads and tails, if the probabilities are substituted into H and T. For instance, one of the terms is 60TH$^{59}$. If you substitute (2/3) in for tails and (1/3) for heads, then the expression 60TH$^{59}$ evaluates to the probability of getting one tails and 59 heads.